# Extracting a field from HTML in Node-Red

Tags: node-red

I am trying to extract two angles (azimuth & altitude) from a website (suncalc) using REST Api inside the Node-Red environment. I get the attribute and the ID, but not the value. The issue arose because of the html output from the REST api. Here's what my flow looks like:

```
[{"id":"c275914f.48426","type":"tab","label":"Flow 5","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"b5b2b310.4dfc5","type":"inject","z":"c275914f.48426","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":180,"y":180,"wires":[["d7e0478a.997b8"]]},{"id":"d7e0478a.997b8","type":"http request","z":"c275914f.48426","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"txt","paytoqs":"ignore","url":"https://suncalc.org/#/48.85826,2.29451,17/2021.09.23/16:40/324.0/2","tls":"","persist":false,"proxy":"","authType":"","x":330,"y":180,"wires":[["a8ff0654.6ac8d"]]},{"id":"a8ff0654.6ac8d","type":"html","z":"c275914f.48426","name":"","property":"","outproperty":"payload","tag":".Bold","ret":"attr","as":"single","x":470,"y":180,"wires":[["984182c2.bb29e8"]]},{"id":"984182c2.bb29e8","type":"debug","z":"c275914f.48426","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":590,"y":180,"wires":[]}]`
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The values on the suncalc page are dynamically updated by Javascript once the page has loaded, so all the fields in the HTML have placeholders that get replaced once the page is fully loaded and all the Javascript has run. This is probably done on purpose specifically to prevent people doing what you are trying to do.

You can not scrape the values from the static html.

There should be no need to scrape the page as there are a [number of nodes](https://flows.nodered.org/search?term=suncalc) in the Node-RED flow library that will provide the same data, if they do not meet all your needs they should provide examples you can build on.